# MongoDB query for null using dot syntax

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Im having trouble querying mongodb for null values using the [dot syntax of mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-for-an-element-by-the-array-index-position).

Some things in a db:

```
db.things.insertMany([
   { a: [{ value: 1 }] },
   { a: [{ value: null }] },
   { a: [{ value: 2 }] }
]);
```

I want to find all of the documents which have the first element in the 'a' array having a null value.

Queries:

`db.getCollection('things').count({ "a.0.value": 1 })` => 1 (as expected)
`db.getCollection('things').count({ "a.0.value": null })` => 3 **(I would expect 1 here also)**

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this is returning all the elements for the second query. It only seems to have this behaviour for array indexed results, which also makes it kind of weird. (eg `db.getCollection('things').count({ "a": null })` => 0 as expected)

The only thing I can think of is that its basically cancelling out the whole statement when it has the value null but I don't know how to get around this.

**MongoDB** v3.4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) to use aggregation operator and then find the first index using [**`$arrayElemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) which is [**`$eq`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/)ual to  `null`

```
db.collection.find({ "$expr": { "$eq": [{ "$arrayElemAt": ["$a.value", 0] }, null] } })
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xH0dDUEma9h)

For the mongo version prior to **3.6**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "match": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$a.value", 0] }
  }},
  { "$match": { "match": null }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hxhYUqZnu-e)

If you even want to check with `.dot` syntax then you have to use [**`$type`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#op._S_type) operator to compare with the `null` values

```
db.collection.find({ "a.0.value": { "$type": 10 } })
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ljT1NSzDXQb)

Comment: Hey, I think that would work if I were in a newer mongo, but I'm in 3.4.10. Do you know if theres something similar for that version?

Comment: Actually even using 3.6 I get no results with that query (im using this repl: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/)

Comment: Do you happen to know why dot syntax works for other things but not null?

Comment: Updated my answer again